# SharePoint 2013 Term can not be shared multiple times in same term set

Tags: 2013, managed-metadata

I want to reuse a term in 2 different term.

[image]

As shown in Image I reused Search term in SharePoint 2010 Term. Now I also want to use Search Term in SharePoint 2013 Term...

But I am getting error that Term can not be shared multiple times in same term set.....

Answer (score -1):

Terms can be re-used across term sets, which sort of (but not quite) enables polyhierarchies.

Please follow the blog : http://www.sharepointsharon.com/2011/09/sharepoint-2010-taxonomy-limits/

Comment: Link broken. I have a list of states that applies multiple times to parents - surely I could reuse the list as children to various term branches?